# How to boot an Acer Aspire V5 from a bootable USB?

Tags: boot, bios, acer-aspire

I cannot boot my Acer Aspire V5-471G from a bootable USB stick. Already altered the BIOS in a way that the USB has priority over HDD, but still nothing happens and Windows 8 boots normally from HDD. It's like the USB stick is not plugged into the laptop at all.

What should I do?

Comment: I never owned an Acer but from reading stories about attempts to install Linux I've learned that Acers often need UEFI password to enable trust for booting external devices.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into BIOS Setup and do the following (might not be exact for your BIOS):

- In the Security tab, if Secure Boot is enabled, using your Arrow and
  <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, disable it or change it to "Setup Mode"
- In the Boot tab, if UEFI mode is enabled, change it to Legacy Boot.

This should now show your USB drive as a bootable device.

Note that if Windows was installed with the BIOS in UEFI mode,
then it may not boot in Legacy mode.

Comment: Is the reason for the downvote that this didn't work for you?

Comment: Worked for me. You might need to set up a BIOS password before being able to modify these changes.

Comment: Also, you might need to disable RAID (BIOS -> Main -> Strg+S -> disable VMD Controller) because that might fix your problem with grub not finding your hdd...

Answer (score 0):

a. remove the USB stick.
b. boot and enter BIOS.
c. reset default settings & reboot.
d. re-enter BIOS.
e. disable "secure boot" and enable the F12 function (which allows you to select the boot f. device on start up)
g. insert the USB stick.
h. save settings and reboot.
i. mash F12

Comment: SuperUser has some nice formatting options in the editor. Your answer would be greatly improved if you used these to add some basic formatting, such as a list.